# RUN Script after sql service up in dockerfile

Tags: sql-server, bash, docker, dockerfile, docker-engine

I have a database for my app and I want to create it in run time docker

I have a file `CreateDB.sh` and it creates all the tables and stored procedure that I want.

I tried this :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y \
    SA_PASSWORD=qwe123QWE

USER root
RUN mkdir /home/db
COPY ./db /home/db
RUN chmod +x /home/db/DbScriptLinux.sh
WORKDIR /home/db/
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/home/db/DbScriptLinux.sh"]
```

but it returns an error :

> LoginTimeout

is there any way to run my script after all services (sql-server) start?

Comment: Make a docker-compose with a service responisble for running a script depending on sql service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if statement, for example, `RUN if [[ -z "$arg" ]] ; then echo Argument not provided ; else echo Argument is $arg ; fi`

Another way would be to use `command1 && command2` so if the command 1 is successfull, then command 2 would run afterwards.

Your last line `CMD ["/bin/bash", "/home/db/DbScriptLinux.sh"]` if this is to start the database every time you start the container, as your default command to run, then should be alright, otherwise it would be better to use the `RUN` command.